# Eclipse - IInAppBillingServide.aidl

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, in-app-billing

I try to implement in-app billing to my LibGDX android project. I install google play billing on SDK and copy IInAppBillingService.aidl to the package com.android.vending.billing and build the project.

I've been following this site: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.
It says "You should see a generated file named IInAppBillingService.java in the /gen directory of your project.", but only the package com.android.vending.billing is generated. It is empty. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

That was becasue in the sdk/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1, aidl.exe is moved to sdk/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/bin. So I uninstalled 23.0.0_rc1 and started to use 22.0.1. Now everything works fine.